# Should COVID excess mortality be corrected afterwards?

Tags: mortality, covid-19

A widespread measure of effect of the COVID pandemic is the excess mortality. Two examples of methodologies to calculate are the calculations of the [European Union statistics office](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Excess_mortality_-_statistics#Excess_mortality_in_the_EU_between_January_2020_and_May_2022) and [the Economist](https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2021/05/13/how-we-estimated-the-true-death-toll-of-the-pandemic).

Basically, a baseline is calculated, with deaths from 5/10 years prior to the pandemic, so the excess of deaths afterwards can be attributable to the COVID pandemic. Of course, other causes may exist, but clearly COVID would be the most important one.

As it is generally seen, after the pandemic has passed a negative excess mortality appears in many countries (I think it is related to the so-called harvesting effect). As I see it, if somebody was going to die in the next few months, from an aggregate point of view, the pandemic is not totally the cause of death. I believe it is important to get the most rigorous picture possible for public health measures.

So, my question is if to properly account for the effects of the pandemic, should this number be subtracted from the total deaths number to have a more accurate picture of the pandemic? Would this correction have a sizeable effect on the total number of deaths?